# How to create static list over session in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I should create buy basket in my website and I would like to use `list<int>` static of id's of products that user selected but when I create this static list

```
public static list<int> Ordered_products;
```

and add item to this list buy

```
 Ordered_products.add(item.id);
```

and show the product name buy id's in `Ordered_products` when multi user insert to the list users can see the product hat another user insert it to the list .

How can I have static list over session?

Comment: You should [think twice about using session state](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/), and follow the advice given in that link. Shopping carts can perform better and be more reliable without it.

Answer (score 2):

Static fields are variables of Application level, it means that everyone have the same instance on it.
What you need is Session variables, check this link: [ASP.NET Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

Comment: can we have session of dictionary or list?

Comment: @amirjahany you still haven't checked my link
`// When retrieving an object from session state, cast it to 
// the appropriate type.
ArrayList stockPicks = (ArrayList)Session["StockPicks"];

// Write the modified stock picks list back to session state.
Session["StockPicks"] = stockPicks;`